# Matrix Transform

Tags: matlab, matrix

I am working on a project in which I need to transform the result matrix to a simpler matrix. More specifically, for each column in matrix, I want to find the maximum value in row and change it to 1, and the rest of the values will be change to 0.  I am not sure how to search this question so I decide to post it here.

For example, I have a matrix X:

```
X = [2 8 4; 7 3 9;1 2 3];
X = 2 8 4
    7 3 9
    1 2 3
```

and I want to transform this matrix to

```
X' = 0 1 0
     1 0 1
     0 0 0
```

I only know how to use for loop to return the maximum value from each row, but I am not sure how to return the position in matrix of that value and convert the rest to zero.

Here is my idea

1. Create a new same dimension zero matrix first
2. Find the maximum value in row
3. Find the position of the maximum value
4. Assign the value 1 into new matrix at same position
5. Repeat 2 and 3 by for loop

I am new to Matlab, hope you can help.

Here is one of the result of my program

```
 2.0680   17.7410    0.8992   -3.0221
 3.6093    7.3443    6.7442    0.9874
-0.9095   -3.3220   -1.4857   -0.0023
-1.1753  -16.7906    0.3672    3.7697
-1.6856   -6.0929   -2.8614    0.5054
 1.0794    3.8352    1.9894    0.1686
-0.4584   -0.3923   -1.2525   -0.4761
```

And I want this matrix transform to

```
0 1 0 0
1 0 1 0
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 1
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
```

So I think the reason why max() not work is becuase I have negative value inside the matrix

Other example which not wotk with max()
  Columns 1 through 5

```
 0.3816   23.2243   19.6435   23.2243   -3.1993
 3.8674    8.0762    6.0563    8.0762    1.8475
-0.4442   -4.0758   -3.4244   -4.0758    0.2073
 0.7639  -22.3618  -19.1365  -22.3618    3.9892
-1.8128   -6.4602   -5.1011   -6.4602   -0.4536
 0.2954    3.5886    3.1529    3.5886   -0.1403
-0.3723    0.8057    0.6607    0.8057   -0.5173
```

Columns 5 through 10

```
 1.4814   19.6435    3.3100   23.2243    1.4814
 7.0255    6.0563    6.5251    8.0762    7.0255
-1.1483   -3.4244   -1.1448   -4.0758   -1.1483
-0.7784  -19.1365   -2.3904  -22.3618   -0.7784
-3.8880   -5.1011   -3.7437   -6.4602   -3.8880
 1.0289    3.1529    0.7994    3.5886    1.0289
-0.3723    0.8057    0.6607    0.8057   -0.5173
```

Columns 11 through 15

```
 21.3957   19.6435    1.4814    0.3816   -3.1993
 8.5765    6.0563    7.0255    3.8674    1.8475
-4.0793   -3.4244   -1.1483   -0.4442    0.2073
-20.7498  -19.1365   -0.7784    0.7639    3.9892
-6.6046   -5.1011   -3.8880   -1.8128   -0.4536
 3.8181    3.1529    1.0289    0.2954   -0.1403
 0.4994    0.6607   -0.5829   -0.3723   -0.5173
```

Columns 16 through 20

```
  -1.7736    9.5635   20.0251    1.8072    0.3816
   1.6114    7.0884    9.9237    3.6313    3.8674
  -0.0058   -2.3835   -3.8685   -0.6572   -0.4442
   2.1941   -8.7540  -18.3726   -1.0312    0.7639
  -0.5815   -4.5430   -6.9138   -1.9407   -1.8128
   0.1232    2.4470    3.4483    0.5589    0.2954
  -0.3588   -0.2377    0.2884   -0.2138   -0.3723
```

The correct answer is use bsxfun(@eq, output, max(output))

Comment: You say "maximum per row", but you show "maximum per column"...which do you mean?

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis Sorry I make a mistake, it should be for each column in matrix, find the row with maximum value, convert it to 1, convert rest of rows to 0. So should be Column

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not entirely sure what you mean, but does

```
>> bsxfun(@eq, X, max(X,[],2))  % maximum per row
ans =
     0     1     0
     0     0     1
     0     0     1
```

Come close? If you mean the maximum per *column*, then just use

```
>> bsxfun(@eq, X, max(X)) % maximum per column
ans =
     0     1     0
     1     0     1
     0     0     0
```

Comment: Thanks, this is actually work. But in my experiment the real matrix contains non positive integer so if use this method the matlab will keep return "Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals." error.  Any way can solve this problem?

Comment: @ShawnLien: Can you give a small example of a more accurate approximation to your real problem?

Comment: I am creating a RBF neural network without NN toolbox and I need to compare to trainging output with the target. Each cell in training output is the value caculate by Gaussian function,so the values will always be double value. I need to transfer the output matrix to the matrix I mention in question and compare it to the target. I just realize that max() only work while the data is all in Integer, hope this is not disturbing

Comment: Shawn, `max` certainly continues to work when some of the data are doubles. Can you post the matrix on which Rody's answer fails to work? And also tell us what answer you think should be correct for that matrix?

Comment: @DanBecker Hey, sorry for reply late,I have edit my question, I think the reason why Rody's method not work is because my matrix contains negative values.

Comment: @ShawnLien: Over here, my method with the matrix you gave produces the exact output you desire...

Comment: Can you help me take a look the other example? I have also edit to the question, its a 7*20 matrix and also want the similar result.  I don't see any particular problem with this matrix but it just keep return "Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals."  error with max()

Comment: @ShawnLien: Aha! now I get it! I think you have a variable called `'max'` somewhere in your workspace. Try `MM=max; clear max;` before using the commands above, and you should be fine. In the future: using variable names that are the same as Matlab functions...is definitely *not* a good idea :)

Comment: I also use round(X) to round that 7*20 matrix to all integer value matrix, but still it show the same error when I tyr to use max()

Comment: @ShawnLien: See my comment above.

Comment: wow...sorry, this is very silly mistake. Now this is finally work, thanks for you continuing help :)

Answer (score 5):

You can use [**bsxfun**](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) to check whether a value is equal to the max of its column.

```
X = bsxfun(@eq, X, max(X))
```

See the documentation I linked to above for more explanation and an example of how bsxfun works.